# VSC++ ошибка LNK2019 при сборке проекта

Tags: c++

Вот код программы:

```
//Упражнение1
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Введите число.";                                 
    return 0;


}
```

При сборке ошибка:

```
1>Компоновка...
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ      _WinMain@16 в функции ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\User\Desktop\Уроки\2\Debug\2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 неразрешенных внешних элементов
1>Журнал построения был сохранен в "file://c:\Users\User\Desktop\Уроки\ \2\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>2 - ошибок 2, предупреждений 0
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

В чем проблема? Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы создаёте проект как "Windows Application" или как "Console Application"? В вашем случае нужно создавать "Console Application".